# Modal Remoteness

Tags: modality

I hope you are having a great day.

*A Student’s Introduction to English Grammar* says that there are two modal construction, open, where we should use the present and remote, where we should use the preterite.
My question concerns the use of the past simple to signal modal remoteness.

If, for example, you and I were looking for something, and I was dead sure that this thing was in a box, which one of the following sentences would be grammatical to use in that case?

- If you didn't find it, I would pay you any amount of money.

Or

-If you don't find it, I will pay you any amount of money.

Thanks.

Comment: They're both valid - which you "should" use depends on the *exact context*. For example, *I gave you instructions for how to get from the station to my house when you come to visit tomorrow. But if you didn't want to walk, I'd reimburse you the cab fare*.

Comment: And "But if you **don't** want to walk I **will** reimburse you the cab fare. (open: present tense)

Comment: @BillJ: True, dat. And I can't really see much scope for any *semantic* difference between the two verb forms with this example. But can you think of a context where both are valid, *and they affect the meaning*?